# How to setup my systemd service ExecStart correctly?

Tags: systemd, services, nodejs

I'm trying to setup a service with systemd services but I'm getting an error and I can't understand what's wrong with it.

```
[Unit]
Description=Vinematik Service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=buraksumer13
ExecStart=/home/buraksumer13/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin node home/buraksumer13/Documents/vinematikIns/index.js  

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get the following error when I run `systemctl status vinematik`:

```
● vinematik.service - Vinematik Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vinematik.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-05-06 16:44:12 UTC; 788ms ago
    Process: 2981 ExecStart=/home/buraksumer13/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin node /home/buraksumer13/Documents/vinematikIns/index.js (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 2981 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

I don't understand why it can not start my script and I'm not quite sure if it's an error. But I do think it could be about my `ExecStart` line, is it setup correctly or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This line don't look well structured `ExecStart=/home/buraksumer13/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin node home/buraksumer13/Documents/vinematikIns/index.js  
`

Comment: `home/buraksumer13/Documents/vinematikIns/index.js` should be `/home/.../...` and `/home/buraksumer13/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin node` should be `/home/buraksumer13/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin/node` no space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these corrections, change this:

```
ExecStart=/home/buraksumer13/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin node home/buraksumer13/Documents/vinematikIns/index.js
```

to

```
ExecStart=/home/buraksumer13/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin/node /home/buraksumer13/Documents/vinematikIns/index.js
```

Comment: Ah, I'm such an idiot. I wasn't looking quite good enough. Thank you, this solved my problem. I should be more careful about these things.

Comment: Great just click the check mark to accept the answer @OnderSumer

Comment: Yep, I was waiting for the four minutes time limit.